# jQuery selectors: is the order of selectors important?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've an html document which looks like this:

```
<div id="panel_comments">
  <table id="panel_comments_table">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 150px;">Monday: </td>
      <td><textarea id="panel_comments_monday" rows="4" cols="60" >Monday comment area</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    .. same with the other 6 weekdays
  </table>
</div>
```

Now, if I want to select all textareas I would do the following, which is in a natural language: `give me all elements which are textareas, with the following ids`:

```
$("textarea [id^=panel_comments_]")
```

but it gives me an empty result. Instead I have to rearrange the selectors like this, which is in a natural language `give me all elements with the ids, and which are textareas`:

```
$("[id^=panel_comments_] textarea")
```

Why does the **ordering of the selectors** matter?

Comment: Make sure you don't end up with few elements with the same id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is significant here, it is the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/). Just omit it:

```
textarea[id^=panel_comments_]
```

---

The reason why `[id^=panel_comments_] textarea` seems to work is that it selects the **`div`** element with ID `panel_comments` and then finds all textareas that are descendants of it. So, this only works "by accident" since the `div` and the `textarea` have similar IDs. Had you given the `div` element a completely different ID, it would not have worked.

---

CSS selectors work on hierarchical structures, like HTML, so it is only reasonable that the order of "sub-selectors" matters.

Only if you don't want to express relations between elements, [the order almost doesn't matter](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax):

> A simple selector is either a *type selector* or *universal selector* followed immediately by zero or more *attribute selectors*, *ID selectors*, or *pseudo-classes*, in any order.

Comment: It was really an 'accident' that it worked the other way round. Thx, especially for the links.

Answer (score 3):

You want this, no extra space:

```
$("textarea[id^=panel_comments_]")
```

Using space as: `$("textarea [id^=panel_comments_]")` means select all elements with IDs inside textarea.

Using: `$("[id^=panel_comments_] textarea")` means select all textarea inside elements with ID starting with your selector string.

Following BoltClock's comment, type selector must be used before any extra filter selector, which means:

- `$("textarea[id^=panel_comments_]")` is valid
- `$("[id^=panel_comments_]textarea")` is not valid

Comment: Also, you can rearrange selectors in a chain in any order, except that a type selector like `textarea` must always come first.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("textarea[id^=panel_comments_]")
```

remove that extra space